# PHP TinyMCE type php in textarea?

Tags: php, function, tinymce

I've just started using TinyMCE and I've looked around in the forums for an answer to my question but all i found was an outdated plugin that could solve my problem.

So back to the question, is it possible to somehow type i.e.  in the textarea and then make it call the function when i retrieve the information from the database?

I've thought about making some type of BBCode ([php] callFunction(); [/php]) to make this work, am I on the right track?

just to make myself clear, please just point me in the right direction!

Comment: Sorry, can you specify what you want to achieve? I didn't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you use [php] callFunction(); [/php] you can use `preg_match()` to find the php code, then use `exec()` to run it.

Make sure you have great security and validate who is logged in and what functions they are trying to run.